# Do I inform a company that I just had an interview with that I have an offer from another company?

Tags: job-offer, new-job

I just had an interview with a company (Company A) and i thought it  went well. if I make it - there will be  a final  culture  fit interview (much  less formal). But I already have an offer that I'm sitting on from another company (Company B). How do I and should I inform Company A about it?

If so, then how can I leverage this to my advantage?

Comment: Do you have a final date to take the offer from B? Is that after you have the final interview with A and receive an offer?

Comment: They are meant to send me a formal offer letter today. So I suppose a week from now is the deadline. The HR from A (the one I just interviewed with today) said they will inform me of an outcome by 48 hours - then I suppose early next week we'll have the culture  fit interview.

Comment: Mind telling us about the second question I asked?  When does the offer you are currently sitting on expire? The offer you already have from company B (I think I mixed A withh B sorry)

Comment: I am meant to receive the official offer letter today from Company B.

Comment: I see... the point I'm trying to reach is: Will you eventually have BOTH offers in hand and be able to decide? Or is timing not the best here and you would have to take a risk and "bluff"?

Comment: I am not sure. B has given me a verbal (via email) offer which I accepted via email. No official offer letter has been sent yet. Since I just gave A's interview today I think I can wait another day before sending an email out saying if there's any way  they can pace up the process. How does that sound?

Answer (score 6):

> How do I and should I inform Company A about it?

> If so, then how can I leverage this to my advantage?

My answer will be a bit different from the answers I usually give.

1. **If timing is on your side**, and you will eventually have *both* offers in hand. Then **just decide on one and inform both companies of your choice** (accept the one you decide, and politely decline and thank the other you decided you didn't want).
2. If timing is not on your side, and you won't have both offers in hand, then I would refer you to these questions for guidance (I also suggest you search on possible posts related or similar that I may have missed):

   - [How to use multiple offers to negotiate a higher salary?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/9338/73791)
   - [Two offers same time. How to negotiate and get the best outcome?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/107753/73791)
   - [How do I coordinate the process of pursuing multiple job opportunities at the same time?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/111/73791)
   - [Should you tell a potential employer with an offer that you're interviewing with another company?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/67179/73791)